# RDF Book Mashup DataSet

Tags: rdf, semantic-web

Is there any sparql endpoint for RDF Book mashup dataset ? and can any one give me example to using it with DBpedia?

Answer (score 0):

There is no SPARQL endpoint for this dataset because it is a wrapper over various Amazon and Google APIs. You can only look up individual resources (products, offers).